# my menu affecting href image

Tags: menu, hyperlink, href

Menu style affects my image when I add link to the image (href), notice the purple affectng the google image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{ float:left; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none;}
a { float:left; width:6em; text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:purple; 
padding:0.2em 0.6em; border-right:1px solid white; }
a:hover
{background-color:#ff3300;}
li {display:inline;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>

<p>
body text
</p>
<a href="test.php" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.google.se/images/google_80wht.gif"

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS rule you've defined for  applies to both your navigation links and the test.php link which includes the Google image.  If you intend to target only the navigation links with that rule there are a variety of approaches but typically you'd apply a class to the element containing the navigation and then alter the rule for navigation links to apply only where that class is present.   Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{ float:left; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none;}
ul.nav a { float:left; width:6em; text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:purple; 
padding:0.2em 0.6em; border-right:1px solid white; }
ul.nav a:hover
{background-color:#ff3300;}
li {display:inline;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>

<p>
body text
</p>
<a href="test.php" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.google.se/images/google_80wht.gif"

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one more issue, @jandersen I lost the hover attribute. Just the google seems to respond to it

Comment: Yep, I noticed that just a minute or two after I posted the answer and then updated it above.  The hover rule should be `ul.nav a:hover` instead of just `a:hover`.   Hope that works as an answer for you ;-)